# What's the most efficient way to split up a Numpy ndarray using percentage?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Hi I'm new to Python & Numpy and I'd like to ask what is the most efficient way to split a ndarray into 3 parts: 20%, 60% and 20%

```
    import numpy as np
    row_indices = np.random.permutation(10)
```

Let's assume the ndarray has 10 items: ***[7 9 3 1 2 4 5 6 0 8]***
The expected results are the ndarray separated into 3 parts like part1, part2 and part3.
***part1:*** [7 9]

***part2:*** [3 1 2 4 5]

***part3:*** [0 8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
# data array
In [85]: a = np.array([7, 9, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0, 8])

# percentages (ratios) array
In [86]: p = np.array([0.2,0.6,0.2]) # must sum upto 1

In [87]: np.split(a,(len(a)*p[:-1].cumsum()).astype(int))
Out[87]: [array([7, 9]), array([3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]), array([0, 8])]
```

Alternative to `np.split` :

`np.split` could be slower when working with large data, so, we could alternatively use a loop there -

```
split_idx = np.r_[0,(len(a)*p.cumsum()).astype(int)]
out = [a[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(split_idx[:-1],split_idx[1:])]
```

Answer (score 2):

I normally just go for the most obvious solution, although there are much fancier ways to do the same. It takes a second to implement and doesn't even require debugging (since it's extremely simple)

```
part1 = [a[i, ...] for i in range(int(a.shape[0] * 0.2))]
part2 = [a[i, ...] for i in range(int(a.shape[0] * 0.2), int(len(a) * 0.6))]
part3 = [a[i, ...] for i in range(int(a.shape[0] * 0.6), len(a))]
```

A few things to notice though

1. This is rounded and therefore you could get something which is only roughly a 20-60-20 split
2. You get back a list of element so you might have to re-numpyfy them with `np.asarray()`
3. You can use this method for indexing multiple objects (e.g. labels and inputs) for the same elements
4. If you get the indices once before the splits (`indices = list(range(a.shape[0]))`) you could also shuffle them thus taking care of data shuffling at the same time